# Write output from dynamic queries in PL/pgSQL to CSV file

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, scripting

```
PG_CMD="psql -d portal -U portal -c "
PG_CMD_TP="psql -d portal -U portal -t -P format=unaligned -c "
abc()
{
 $PG_CMD " 
        DO \$$
        DECLARE
           srowdata record;
           customer_list varchar[];
           customer_schema varchar(100);
           portal_row a.portal%ROWTYPE;
           var1 varchar(100);
           temp varchar(100);
        BEGIN
           customer_list=ARRAY(select cname from customer);

            FOREACH customer_schema IN ARRAY customer_list LOOP 

               EXECUTE format('select %s.portal.*,%s.p_fb_config.*,%s.p_gplus_config.*,%s.p_linkd_config.*,%s.p_localum_config.*,
                   %s.p_sms_config.*,%s.p_twt_config.*,%s.p_webform_config.*,%s.p_wechat_config.*,%s.p_clickthrough_config.*,%s.splash.*
               from %s.portal left outer join %s.p_fb_config on %s.portal.pid = %s.p_fb_config.pid left outer join %s.p_gplus_config 
               on %s.portal.pid = %s.p_gplus_config.pid left outer join %s.p_linkd_config on %s.portal.pid = %s.p_linkd_config.pid left 
               outer join %s.p_localum_config on %s.portal.pid = %s.p_localum_config.pid left outer join %s.p_sms_config on 
               %s.portal.pid = %s.p_sms_config.pid  left outer join %s.p_twt_config on %s.portal.pid = %s.p_twt_config.pid left outer join 
               %s.p_webform_config on %s.portal.pid = %s.p_webform_config.pid left outer join %s.p_wechat_config on 
               %s.portal.pid = %s.p_wechat_config.pid  left outer join %s.p_clickthrough_config on 
               %s.portal.pid = %s.p_clickthrough_config.pid left outer join %s.splash on %s.portal.pid=%s.splash.pid;', customer_schema, 
                   customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,
                   customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema, 
                   customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,
                   customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,
                   customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,
                   customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema,customer_schema) INTO srowdata;

                   raise notice ' %: %', customer_schema,srowdata;
            END LOOP;
        END; 
        \$$";
}

abc
```

I have written anonymous block in plpgsql. Now, instead of using `raise notice` I want to write this output in CSV format. I tried `COPY` but it accepts argument as a query.

Comment: `I tried 'COPY' but it accepts argument as a query` I fail to understand that. Can you clarify? `COPY` should work.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

There is a massively simpler solution.

#### SQL code

After removing much of the cruft, it boils down to this:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   customer_schema text;
BEGIN
   FOR customer_schema IN
      SELECT cname FROM customer
   LOOP 
      EXECUTE format('COPY (
         SELECT p.*, t1.*, t2.* -- etc. Or just: *
         FROM        %1$I.portal         p
         LEFT   JOIN %1$I.p_fb_config    t1 USING (pid)
         LEFT   JOIN %1$I.p_gplus_config t2 USING (pid)
         -- etc.
         ) TO $$/absolute/path/to/my/%1$I_file.csv$$;'
       , customer_schema);
   END LOOP;
 END 
$do$
```

- Simplify the `format()` call. Reuse the same parameter many times. [Read the documentation here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)
- No need to stuff the `cnames` from your `customer` table into an array for processing. Just use a [`FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).
- Standard techniques like table aliases and the `USING` clause help to simplify SQL code.

#### Shell function

Adding that back into your **shell function**:

```
PG_CMD_TP="psql -d portal -U portal -t -P format=unaligned -c "
abc()
{
 $PG_CMD_TP '
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   customer_schema text;
BEGIN
   FOR customer_schema IN
      SELECT cname FROM customer
   LOOP 
      EXECUTE format($f$COPY (
         SELECT *
         FROM        %1$I.portal         p
         LEFT   JOIN %1$I.p_fb_config    t1 USING (pid)
         LEFT   JOIN %1$I.p_gplus_config t2 USING (pid)
         ) TO $p$/absolute/path/to/my/%1$s_file.csv$p$;$f$
       , customer_schema);
   END LOOP;
 END 
$do$';
}

abc
```

Voilá.

- Enclose the whole query in **single quotes** for the scope of the shell. Unlike with double quotes the shell does not try any substitutions and the string is passed as is (special characters like `$` lose their special meaning, too).
- Switch to dollar-quoting in the plpgsql code to go along with the outer single quotes in the shell (or escape all single quotes properly).
- For a quick solution I named the output files after `customer_schema` in the example. You may need to sanitize it to be a legal for filename syntax.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is maybe not the right approach.
what you want is ...

```
COPY (SELECT ...) TO 'some_file_name' CSV;
```

the crux might be your loop. you can get rid around that one easy: there is a function called unnest, which can transform an array into a table which can then be joined or whatever (via a LATERAL join maybe).

you are on the wrong path with your approach.
if you really want this loop and so on, you need a set returning function and use it inside COPY.

Comment: The problem there that to OP wants to use dynamic schema specification.

Comment: copy can only write output of query.I want to pass variable along with it(customer_schema).

Comment: as i said: in this case put things into a procedure returning "setof record" and use copy. you can do anything inside a procedure.